# Georeferencing a raster image in a Mosaic Dataset greyed out in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, georeferencing, pansharpening, worldview-2

I have a Worldview 2 product from Digital Globe. To add it to ArcGIS I am first creating a Mosaic Dataset and selecting the Worldview 2 product definition and setting the coordinate system to be the same as the Map layer. And then using Add Raster to Mosaic Dataset by specifying the folder where the product is located and using the Pansharpened Acomp processing template (I have both the MS and Pan products of Worldview 2 and would like to use a pansharpened RGB image).

I need to georeference this image to align it with another image by manually adding some control points.

However, when I select the image layer, the Georeference button in the Imagery tab is greyed out.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known equivalency idea/enhancement for ArcGIS Pro and one does not have the ability to georeference mosaic dataset.

1. **Single Band Raster with Georeferencing enabled:**

[image]

2. **Mosaic Dataset with greyed out option:**

[image]

But, moving ahead you have 2 options:

1. If you want to georeference the mosaic dataset, export the imagery and perform the corrections

**And**

2. If you want to georef items within the mosaic dataset, use ArcMap

[Georeferencing a mosaic dataset item](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/georeferencing-a-mosaic-dataset-item.htm)

Comment: Are you able to include a link to the ArcGIS Idea that you mention?